# MVC Best practice, responsive design or dynamically serving different html

Tags: css, model-view-controller, web-applications, responsive-design

Creating a web site which may be accessed by various devices, such as pc, tablet or mobile devices. What would be the best practice to ensure that each device is served with a user friendly view?

Earlier I've been rerouting request to separate url's, by having domain.com for my main traffic, mobile devices are being rerouted to m.domain.com.

Starting on a new website, I am wondering whether I should choose another approach:

- Responsive design (css/js) to handle different screen sizes
- Dynamically serving different HTML by having the controller determine device

The third option is of course to use subdomains for different devices.

I do believe that having the controller decide which html (view) to render would fit very well in the MVC method, so this is most likely the direction in which I'm headed.

Still, I'd appreciate any experience or thoughts you might have about this.

Comment: personally i believe using responsive design is better as you just use css/js to hide the parts that dont show well on devices, and plus instead of having to update 2 views (the mobile view and the non-mobile view) when you make changes to the structure of the underlying data for the views, you only have to update one.

Comment: I am worried about the views/css/js might become more complex and harder to maintain using that approach. But I do not have any experience with it. I know there are some frameworks out there that might help

Comment: Well in my use its within a template system, so the responsive code goes in the main template file,and the views just use the predefined css responsive classes where needed Plus use a library like bootstrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap which is great for doing responsive layouts. It includes both a css and js file that has the predefined code in them and you just use their classes, like `row-fluid` class on a parent item with two children items having `span9`,`span3` which makes it so those two children are side by side and with like 64% and 36% width respective. There is a lot of stuff

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar with zurb, but bootstrap was new to me. Thank you for your comments. Appreciated!

Comment: Each website (and team) need a different solution. Without knowing this website: impossible to answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CSS` media queries to target the device.

This would allow you to define custom selectors for devices with different screen widths, for example you could alter the width of your navigation for devices that are viewing your website with a maximum device width of 600px.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation {
    width:200px;
  }
}
</style>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries